# Question: Probability theory, Probability space

Tags: probability, probability-theory

[image]

Can anybody point me in the right direction of this question, please?

Specifically, I'm stuck about constructing the probability space $(\Omega ,{\mathcal {F}},P)$ and constructing this random variable $X$ that has a standard normal distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\Omega =\mathbb  R$, $\mathcal F$ be the Borel sigma algebra and $P$ the probability measure defined by $P(E)=\int_E \frac 1 {\sqrt {2\pi}} e^{-x^{2}/2}dx$. Let $X(\omega)=\omega$ for all $ \omega$. Then $X$ is  a random variable with the given distribution.
Note that $P(X \leq x)=P((-\infty,x])=\int_{-\infty} ^{x} \frac 1 {\sqrt {2\pi}} e^{-t^{2}/2}dt$. Hence $X$ has the given distribution.

Comment: Thank you, what are your thoughts about constructing the probability space? Also, how do you prove that $X$ does indeed have a standard normal distribution?

Comment: @JKong The construction in my answer works for any distribution, not just standard normal distribution. I have now included a proof of the fact that$X$ has the given  distribution.